# CSS - make the left+right borders exact same height as the text

Tags: css

Take a look at the following code, which is a simplified version of a bigger problem I'm having:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
        div {border-width:0px 5px; border-style:solid; border-color:black; width:400px; margin:0; padding:0; background:red;}
        div:nth-child(2) {background:green;}
        p {color:yellow; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:40px;margin:0;padding:0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><p>Hello World</p></div>
<div><p>Hello World</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It should create something like this:

[image]

What the client has asked for is for the black left border and black right border to be the exact same height as the yellow text.  That is, the height of the black bars should not include the extra space between the top+bottom of the yellow text and top+bottom of the container.

One way I can think of doing this is to set a fixed height on the containing div, then give the div an overflow:hidden.  Next I will use a negative margin-top on the p tag.

Can anyone think of a better approach?  I really don't like the approach I mentioned because my client is a design nazi and will expect things to be pixel perfect across all the different operating systems, different browsers, and different screen resolutions.  From my experience, if I try to position elements by hard coding pixel values into my CSS, and those elements still need to be relative to elements that vary in size (due to dynamic content), it can be a night mare.

Are my concerns warranted?  If so, is there a better way to make the borders exactly the same height as the text?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jm5Dw/4/)

Just set the line-height below the height of the container so that the font occupies it without any left over space.

```
p{    
font-size:40px;
line-height:30px;
}
```

Comment: Almost.  I changed the line-height to 27px.  The space between top of text is gone.  But there is space at the bottom of hte text.  If I reduce the line-height any more, the top of the text starts to get overflow.  I do not want the text to overflow OR cropped.

Comment: Set the `line-height` to `26px` and add `2px` of `padding-top`. That should fit just right. I updated the above jsFiddle with this code.

Comment: Do you know if this will render exactly pixel perfect across all the browsers, operating system, desktop vs. mobile and screen resolutions?  I will do some tests once i get back into the office.  Because i noticed in the past that sometimes when you try to align things absolutely via pixels, it might be off depending on your environment, and you end up seeing gaps.

Comment: Ok I converted the units into `em` and tested on the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE. All seem to work fine. I even played with resolution and had no issues. Please do test it because I am sure there will be some platform this won't work on, it is simply how coding works. If you really want pixel-perfect results, use images. All I can say is, this is as close as I can get with code:http://jsfiddle.net/Jm5Dw/6/

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this using pseudo-elements (no <= IE8 support). Note that the border is a little larger than the font, that is just the nature of the font allowing a little space above and below (notice that both are set to `40px`). This can't really be helped cross-platform/browser/etc. unless you want to make an image that is pixel perfect.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/Ugbrk/)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div><p class="fancy-border">Hello World</p></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fancy-border {
    position:relative;
}
.fancy-border:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    border-width:0px 5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-20px;
    left:-5px;
}
```

Comment: Hey Tyriar, as you may have noticed, I do not want the "font allowing a little space above and below".  So are you saying my two options are either use images or go with the approach I mentioned in my question?  I think both are unmaintainable ways to do things.  Even though the client is asking for it

Comment: Perhaps a different font will draw exactly. I agree they are both bad and unmantainable solutions but that's the way that fonts work, as you can see we're drawing then at the exact same size.

Comment: I needed to draw a status bar in front of some text and this solution worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

give borders on P tag and set the line height of p so that there remains no space between lines then give margin between them